# Pandas Assert error for identical columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-unittest

Trying to assert two pandas dataframe using.

`pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, expected_df, check_dtype=False)`

Getting the error as below.
But if you see properly, both left and right have the exact same value.

```
AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 9] (column name="Stores") are different

DataFrame.iloc[:, 9] (column name="Stores") values are different (100.0 %)
[left]:  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...]
[right]: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...]
```

Comment: Firstly, if you're checking identical dataframes, why is the `check_dype` parameter set to `False`? Secondly, could you show us how you're generating the data to populate these dataframes?

Comment: I am doing the unittest to verify if my deployments have made any changes in the results. df is the results that is stored in postgres by my code.
df  - I am pulling from postgres DB. Its a simple select * query
expected_df - I had pulled from postgres before deployment of some codes. 

I am trying to do a unittest to confirm if my codes have made any affect to the results now.

Comment: Does pandas.DataFrame.equals give you the same result? Why is check_dtype set to False , what are the dtypes? How about the indexes, are they the same? What does df['Stores'] - df_expected['Stores'] return? Have you played with the other parameters as explained in the docs? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

Comment: @RakeshSK, if `df` is populated via that query, where is `expected_df` populated from? As we can't see your data, we are limited in our ability to help more than provide these suggestions.

Comment: @Dbercules Both are from the derived from the same DB. Its just that expected_df was downloaded and kept as CSV in local before deployment. df was downloaded from postgres after code deployment

Answer (score 1):

Check that the column types are the same. I had a similar problem when I was reading data from a postgresql table and the int column was declared as text. Then after reading the data from the database and writing it to a csv file, a column of type string with int values is written the same as a column of type int. After reading the same file, this column automatically gets type int. As string and int are not comparable it returns AsserationError

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32926683)